# Which function calls when "Save and continue Edit" click on Add Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, adminhtml

I want to know the file and location of function which works on click of "Save and continue Edit". And how i change redirect url in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection URL is in **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php** -> `public function saveAction()` and more specifically this:

```
if ($redirectBack) {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
        'id'    => $productId,
        '_current'=>true
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see code in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php`
`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit`

but It's not good to change core file please place your file in

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php
```

and change it as per your requirement

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('popup')) {
            if (!$this->getProduct()->isReadonly()) {
                $this->setChild('save_and_edit_button',
                    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                        ->setData(array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
                            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
                            'class' => 'save'
                        ))
                );
            }
```

Comment: But which function calls on the button. Means after click on button page refresh so which function redirect page.

Comment: please check i have updated my answer